# Excel VBA: setting cell value based on a search

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set the ActiveCell's value as follows:

- I need to look at the value of the cell that is one row above the active cell (in the same column)
- I then need to find this value in the 3rd column of the 'Source - Questions' sheet; I need to start the search from the bottom going up because I need to find the last instance of this value
- When I find this cell I need to take the value of the next cell that is just under the cell that was found (in the same column)

This is my code, I get an exception without any helpful information.

```
ActiveCell.Value = Cells.Find(What:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value, 
After:=Sheets("Source - Questions").Cell(1000, 3), LookIn:=xlFormulas, 
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, 
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, 0).Value
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the two small errors:

```
Sub asdf()
    Dim r As Range, s As Worksheet, v As Variant
    Set s = Sheets("Source - Questions")
    v = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    Set r = s.Cells.Find(What:=v, _
        After:=s.Cells(1000, 3), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, 0)
    ActiveCell.Value = r.Value
End Sub
```